# Twig and Symfony2 - Entity was not found

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, entity

I have an entity that is related to some other entities.
On the end, I have an object like tat:

```
paper.submission.authors
```

For some of the paper.submission, there is no author, and in my twig template, I am doing:

```
{% for author in paper.submission.authors}
    do something
{% endfor %}
```

And for the paper.submission with no authors, I am getting "Entity was not found" exception.

Is thee any possibility to test if the object exists before my for loop.

I have try the is defined, it is always true. Then, I have tryed is not null, but this is also generating the exception.

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Are you sure that paper.submission is always set ?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

### Problem

Doctrine throws this Exception when it doesn't find the related entity. It seems redundant to say this, but in fact this is important.
It means it *could* find an ID related to it, but the request doctrine made didn't match any result.

My guess is that your database table (link table actually) `submission.authors` contains IDs of `0` instead of `NULL`.
With such, Doctrine thinks there **IS** an author with ID of `0`, and therefor, cannot find it.

### What happens

`submission.authors` always exists. It is an *Uninitialized* Doctrine Proxy.

```
var_dump($submission->getAuthors());
```

Would show you what contains exactly `submission.authors`
At this point, no queries are made. It simply returns a [`PersistentCollection`](http://www.doctrine-project.org/api/orm/2.2/source-class-Doctrine.ORM.PersistentCollection.html) with a flag [`isInitialized`](http://www.doctrine-project.org/api/orm/2.2/source-class-Doctrine.ORM.PersistentCollection.html#320-328) to false.

The exception occurs when you're trying to get a property out of it

```
foreach ($submission->getAuthors() as $author) {
}
```

When doing this doctrine will check if `getAuthors` is initialized. If not, it will run the following query

```
SELECT <stuffs> FROM authors WHERE id = 0;
```

Which returns no match and will throw an [`EntityNotFound`](http://www.doctrine-project.org/api/orm/2.2/class-Doctrine.ORM.EntityNotFoundException.html) Exception

### Fix

You must set your id row's default to `NULL` and make a query to update all `0`'s to `NULL`.
With this, you can easily test `submission.authors` with `is not null`

Doctrine will not run any query if it finds a `NULL`

Comment: This error also occurs if one of your database tables is corrupt. This sometimes happens with my MYISAM-tables. You can fix it by repairing the respective table: `REPAIR TABLE yourTable`

Comment: This also will happen with relations, I had this issue and my entity 'A', there was not any relation on it, but there was another entity 'B' that was pointing to 'A' has ManyToOne, this entity 'B' was having some values of 0 in the relational field, so was causing this error.

Answer (score 8):

**How to debug to find which related entity was not found?**

Exception message improved in repository  https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2/blob/master/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Proxy/ProxyFactory.php#L160 but if you use older version you can do the following debugging.

**If you use older version**

Put following code to ProxyFactory class before `throw new EntityNotFoundException();` line vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Proxy/ProxyFactory.php:177

```
$entity = $classMetadata->getReflectionClass()->getShortName();
$id = $classMetadata->getIdentifierValues($proxy)['id'];
var_dump("$entity WHERE id = $id NOT FOUND.");exit;
throw new EntityNotFoundException();
```

Comment: Very useful for identifying bugs

Answer (score 7):

In your entity you can made something like this:

```
public function getSubmission(){
    if($this->Submission->getId()==0) return null;
    return $this->Submission;
}
```

Comment: Thanks it works for me. Sometimes, I have a property in my Entity A that's define but corresponds to nothing in the Entity B and I had this error in my twig file even if I check if the related entity is defined or not.