# How to escape Twig errors on an entity not found in Symfony2

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, entity, twig

I am having a heck of a time trying to escape twig errors when an entity is not found.

I have a table called listings and it has a relationship to warehouses. If a warehouse is deleted, then I am getting this error in Twig "An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("Entity was not found.")".

I have tried all of these options to suppress this error, but I cannot seem to accomplish anything. Please help if you can. Thanks!

```
 {% if inventoryLocation.Warehouse.name is defined %}
 {{ inventoryLocation.Warehouse.name }}
 {% endif %}
 Created this error: "An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("Entity was not found.")"

 {% if inventoryLocation.Warehouse %}
 {{ inventoryLocation.Warehouse.name }}
 {% endif %}
 Created this error: "An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("Entity was not found.")"

 {% if inventoryLocation.Warehouse is not null %}
 {{ inventoryLocation.Warehouse.name }}
 {% endif %}
 Created this error: "An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("Entity was not found.")"

 {% if inventoryLocation.Warehouse sucks because its not there %}
 {{ inventoryLocation.Warehouse.name }}
 {% endif %}
 Doesn't really do anything it just makes me really mad :)
```

Comment: try `if inventoryLocation.warehouse`

Comment: Inside your controller, verify that $inventoryLocation->getWarehouse() is returning a null.

Comment: Are you sure that the error is at the specified location and for the `warehouse` entity? I usually use the second option and it works just fine. Also take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17338105/twig-and-symfony2-entity-was-not-found

Answer (score 1):

I have solved this type of problem by creating a custom getter within my entity or entities that are being iterated on.

For instance - in your case - you have an InventoryLocation and a Warehouse.  It looks like you are displaying or iterating on the InventoryLocation entity.

In that case - I would create a custom getter within the InventoryLocation entity that looks something like this:

```
<?php

public function getWarehouseName()
{
    // Get the associated Warehouse
    if ($this->getWarehouse())
    {
        // Return Warehouse name
        return $this->getWarehouse()->getName();
    }
    else
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Then - in your Twig template - you can call this customer getter method and add in a default if the getter returns NULL.

```
 {{ inventoryLocation.warehouseName | default('-') }}
```